# Why is MatConvNet library not working when I run vl_nnrelu?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I was doing the [practical/exercises](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/cnn/index.html#fnref:lattice) to learn to use MatConvNet and tried running:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Part 1.2: Non-linear gating (ReLU)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

w = single(repmat([1 0 -1], [1, 1, 3])) ;
w = cat(4, w, -w) ;
y = vl_nnconv(x, w, []) ;
z = vl_nnrelu(y) ;

figure(6) ; clf ; colormap gray ;
subplot(1,2,1) ; vl_imarraysc(y) ;
subplot(1,2,2) ; vl_imarraysc(z) ;
```

but when I do I get an error message on `z = vl_nnrelu(y) ;` as follows:

```
Error using vl_argparse (line 52)
The name of the parameter number 1 is not a string.

Error in vl_nnrelu (line 34)
opts = vl_argparse(opts, varargin, 'nonrecursive') ;

Error in exercise1 (line 52)
z = vl_nnrelu(y) ;
```

this seems very bizarre to me. I am also not running the matconvnet library they provide with their tutorial because it seemed not to work for me (instead got the latest one from their website...). Is anyone else experiencing a similar error?

Answer (score 5):

This problem arises due to using **vl_argparse** from VLFeat instead of MatConvNet. To resolve this issue, load the **vl_setup** (VLFeat setup) first and then load the **vl_setupnn** (MatConvNet setup).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem today and started looking into the vl_argparse.m file from which the error was coming.

I had actually no idea what the vl_nnrelu function had to do with this so I commented the following out in 'vl_nnrelu.m':

```
% opts = vl_argparse(opts, varargin, 'nonrecursive') ;
```

Then I tried running the exercise1 file again and it worked.